# XamDataGrid sort in Reverse Order

Tags: wpf, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I have xamdatagrid in which I Add Item, every time new item added it goes to the bottom. I want every time I add item it should be on the top row "like reverse sort"
also in field layout setting I am adding new record on top.

note: I removed sort option from field
Note: I dont want to sort by any field except by row insertion order if its in xamdatagrid.
or sort of list like list.reverse possibility in xamdatagrid.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're binding your grid to an `ObservableCollection`, use the `Insert(0, item)` method.

You can also use a `CollectionViewSource` for your grid's data source and set the sort there, while calling `Add(item)` on your source collection normally.